# Modifying map point in D3 v4 after creation

Tags: topojson, d3.js

I have a D3v4 map and I would like to be able to make changes to the points (change size, color, etc.) after they have been drawn.  I have searched, read various D3 tutorials, copied bits from other maps and tried lots of different variations of g.selectAll(".place").attr("d", path.pointRadius(5)), including .data, etc. and nothing seems to have an effect.

Can someone tell me how to construct the statement that would allow me to select these points (paths, actually) after they have been created and apply a different point radius or other styling on them?

The code below just shows a handful of points rather than a full map.

```
var msoac = {"type":"Topology","arcs":[],"transform":{"scale":[0.0008059840222022202,0.0005849051685168519],"translate":[-6.311690349,49.9156999]},"objects":{"msoa_centroids_geo":{"type":"GeometryCollection","geometries":[{"type":"Point","properties":{"MSOA11CD":"E02002536","MSOA11NM":"Stockton-on-Tees 002"},"coordinates":[6223,8027]},{"type":"Point","properties":{"MSOA11CD":"E02002537","MSOA11NM":"Stockton-on-Tees 003"},"coordinates":[6246,8028]},{"type":"Point","properties":{"MSOA11CD":"E02002534","MSOA11NM":"Redcar and Cleveland 020"},"coordinates":[6524,7885]},{"type":"Point","properties":{"MSOA11CD":"E02002535","MSOA11NM":"Stockton-on-Tees 001"},"coordinates":[6234,8046]},{"type":"Point","properties":{"MSOA11CD":"E02002532","MSOA11NM":"Redcar and Cleveland 018"},"coordinates":[6518,7901]},{"type":"Point","properties":{"MSOA11CD":"E02002533","MSOA11NM":"Redcar and Cleveland 019"},"coordinates":[6506,7886]},{"type":"Point","properties":{"MSOA11CD":"E02002530","MSOA11NM":"Redcar and Cleveland 016"},"coordinates":[6650,7904]},{"type":"Point","properties":{"MSOA11CD":"E02002538","MSOA11NM":"Stockton-on-Tees 004"},"coordinates":[6230,8002]},{"type":"Point","properties":{"MSOA11CD":"E02002539","MSOA11NM":"Stockton-on-Tees 005"},"coordinates":[6150,8020]},{"type":"Point","properties":{"MSOA11CD":"E02005740","MSOA11NM":"Northumberland 020"},"coordinates":[5880,8927]}]}}}

var width = 960,
    height = 1160;


var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .call(d3.zoom().on("zoom", function () {
        svg.attr("transform", "translate(" + transform.x + "," + transform.y + ") scale(" + transform.k + ")")
        }));

g = svg.append("g");


var projection = d3.geoAlbers()
    .center([0, 52.4])
    .rotate([4.4, 0])
    .parallels([50, 60])
    .scale(6000)
    .translate([width / 2, height / 2]);

var path = d3.geoPath()
    .projection(projection);

g.selectAll(".points_10")
    .data(topojson.feature(msoac, msoac.objects.msoa_centroids_geo).features)
    .enter().append("path")
    .attr("d", path)
    .attr("d", path.pointRadius(3))
    .attr("class", "place");
```

Thanks in advance to anyone offering assistance.  I'm hopeful this is very easy for someone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be pretty straight forward:

```
var points = g.selectAll(".points_10")
.data(topojson.feature(msoac, msoac.objects.msoa_centroids_geo).features)
.enter().append("path")
.attr("d", path.pointRadius(3))
.attr("class", "place")

// and then something like:
points
.transition()
   .attr("d", path.pointRadius(50)) 
   .attr("fill","yellow")
   .duration(2000)
.transition()
   .attr("fill","steelblue")
   .duration(1000)
.transition()
   .attr("stroke-width",5)
   .attr("stroke","orange")
   .duration(1000)
.transition()
   .attr("stroke-width",1)
   .attr("stroke","steelblue")
   .attr("fill","black")
   .attr("d",path.pointRadius(5))
   .duration(1000);
```

Comment: Thanks for the thorough response.  That is already very helpful.  I hadn't considered "holding on" to the points by making a variable.